# Базы данных Автомобили

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, access

> Используя схему БД автомобильного салона с таблицами Brand – марки автомобилей, Auto – доступные для покупки автомобили, составить запрос для поиска количества и общей стоимости автомобилей каждой марки (в определенный момент времени в салоне может не быть автомобилей конкретной марки):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал примерно вот так и ничего не получилось, что подскажите может

```
SELECT А.Nom_avt,А.MOD, COUNT(*) AS Kolv
FROM Автомобили А
GROUP BY А.MOD,А.Nom_avt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для SQLite3 будет так:

```
SELECT 
 Brand.BrandName AS Brand, 
 COUNT(Auto.Price) AS Count,
 CASE WHEN SUM(Auto.Price) THEN SUM(Auto.Price) ELSE 0.0 END AS Price
FROM 
 Brand 
LEFT JOIN
 Auto ON Brand.BrandId = Auto.BrandId
GROUP BY
 Brand.BrandId
ORDER BY
 Brand.BrandName ASC
```

Другой вариант того же:

```
SELECT 
 Brand.BrandName AS Brand, 
 COUNT(Auto.Price) AS Count,
 IFNULL(SUM(Auto.Price), 0.0) AS Price
FROM 
 Brand 
LEFT JOIN
 Auto ON Brand.BrandId = Auto.BrandId
GROUP BY
 Brand.BrandId
ORDER BY
 Brand.BrandName ASC
```

Возможно и на акцесе получится норм.